# independence between layout and code in Android platform

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

If Android uses XML layout to separate Java code from application layout, why I have to specify the Java class in Fragments layout, like the code below? In this case, if I alter the class name (Java code), I must alter the XML layout too. It doesn't sound like independence to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="course.examples.fragments.staticlayout.TitlesFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="course.examples.fragments.staticlayout.QuotesFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why I have to specify the Java class in Fragments layout, like the code below?

The vast majority of the XML elements in a layout resource specify a Java class name. In your example, `LinearLayout` is a Java class name.

The `LayoutInflater` logic looks at the element name and treats it as a Java class name, except for a few specialized element names like `fragment`. Sometimes, that Java class name is a fully-qualified one, for a class from a library (e.g., `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`) or one of your own (e.g., `com.commonsware.cwac.RecyclerViewEx`). Where the Java class name is without a package (e.g., `LinearLayout`), `LayoutInflater` looks for it in a few well-known Java packages (e.g., `android.widget`).

In the case of `<fragment>`, the class name happens to be in the form of a `class` attribute, perhaps to help the `LayoutInflater` distinguish between a view and a fragment.

> In this case, if I alter the class name (Java code), I must alter the XML layout too.

Correct. This is no different than with most other elements in a layout resource.

> If Android uses XML layout to separate Java code from application layout

Android uses layout resources to help with handling different configurations (e.g., portrait/landscape, small/large screen). Secondarily, layout resources help isolate UI configuration from Java code, in part to be easier for tools like IDEs to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

I will add some more and simple explanations to CommonWare' answer

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="course.examples.fragments.staticlayout.QuotesFragment" />
```

using `fragment` tag inside `XML` is just like an another View (`Button`,`ImageView`.....). In this case you don't have to add `fragment` to layout in `Java code`. System will automatically add `fragment` to your layout and `fragment` will behave static as you cannot replace it with other `fragment` at runtime.To change fragment at runtime, you have to add `fragment` by yourself in `Java code` into a fragment container like `FrameLayout`.